# How to wait for a certain period of time in Perl on Linux

Tags: linux, perl

I want a Perl script to check a certain PID every couple of minutes and then kill the process.  How do I wait those couple of minutes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

[`sleep (n);`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) where n is the number of seconds you want to sleep.

Answer (score 12):

### Crontab

---

If you want a Perl program to execute at a set time or time interval, then you might want to consider `crontab` or another scheduler.

### Perl

---

If you want perform a wait from within the Perl script, you have a few easily deployable options.

#### System Calls

1. `sleep($n)` system call where $n is a numeric value for seconds
2. `usleep($n)` system call where $n is a numeric value for microseconds

#### Perl Modules

[Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) provides a number of functions, some of which override the system calls.  Some of the functions include: `sleep()`, `usleep()`, `nanosleep()`,`alarm()`, `ualarm()`

Unlike the system call to `usleep()`, the one packaged with [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) allows for sleeping more than a second.

```
use Time::HiRes qw( usleep ualarm gettimeofday tv_interval nanosleep
                    clock_gettime clock_getres clock_nanosleep clock
                    stat );
```

#### Suggestion

You'll most likely want to fork your process so that your main program can continue working while that one process is in sleeping in the background.

Comment: +1 for nanosleep(), first Time::HiRes answer, and usleep differences

Comment: Because it's minutes, the best idea is to not tie up any more resources than need be and just use a scheduler.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`sleep()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html):

```
sleep(120);  # sleep for 120 seconds
```

For delays of *finer granularity than one second*, you could use `usleep` from the [`Time::HiRes`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) module. You may also use Perl's four-argument version of [`select()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) leaving the first three arguments undefined:

```
select(undef, undef, undef, 0.25);  # sleep for 250 milliseconds
```

Comment: usleep is better for fine control. Select will (and does) work, but its really supposed to be used for networking.

Comment: +1.  select avoids SIGALRM muckery, as documented under perlfunc/sleep.

Comment: Time::HiRes redefines `sleep` in one that accepts fractional seconds.

Comment: @Chris Huang-Leaver: the quoted line with `select` comes right ouf of the Perl documentation (`perldoc -f select`). This is official Perl's way to sleep for less than a second. Other bells and whistles are implemented in the optional `Time::HiRes` module.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `sleep($numSeconds);`

So to wait 2 minutes, you would execute `sleep(120);`

[perldoc -f sleep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html)

Answer (score 1):

or you could try `usleep(microseconds)` if a whole second is too long.
`sleep(0)` simply yields to the OS, (discarding what time your process has left on the scheduler).  Note that all these functions you ask for the *minimum* amount of time you want to sleep. The time may be slightly longer on a heavily loaded system.

sleep and usleep are C functions, although Perl, python etc. have functions which call the underling C ones. 
[usleep man page, BSD version, (others are available, try Google)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/usleep/)

Comment: +1  Don't know why you got a downvote.  `usleep` isn't my preferred approach, but it certainly works.

Comment: @pilcrow, Chris: `usleep` is not available in vanilla Perl. And there is no mention of Time::HiRes which is de facto standard module for the purpose. That's why the response got down voted.

Comment: @pilcrow, Chris: and BTW/FYI, `usleep` even as a syscall is now deprecated (since POSIXv6/SUSv3) in favor of `nanosleep`.

Comment: @Dummy00001, thanks for clarifying.  Uncommented downvotes are frustrating, IMHO, robbing everyone of the chance for a good discussion and an education.

Comment: My bad, didn't see the 'in Perl' bit, or did you edit the question title? :-)